# Azure CDN Rules to redirect path to different origin

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

My aim is to host various microsites using Azure Statics App and then have these registered as origins in CDN.

When the user would then browse to https://www.example.com/path1, static app1 (origin1) should serve the content where as https://www.example.com/path2 should be served by static app2 (origin2).

I have tried to use the Rules engine and then setup a condition, if url path begins with `/path1*` with an action to override the origin group, but this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas what should be done here?